# Publisher phrases in html

Tags: wysiwyg, publisher

Is there a way to enable a wysiwyg editor for editing phrases in Publisher?

I am aware that you could actually add html tags into phrases. But it would be a great addition, if there was an add-on that actually could convert some phrase input fields into a simple wysiwyg editors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently don't have plans to implement a wysiwyg editor for the phrases.

Also, StackExchange is not my official support channel. Please use boldminded.com/support in the future.